# Concatenate strings of digits in matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, type-conversion

Suppose I have a series of strings such as:

```
a = '101010101010'
b = '010101'
c = '000101010'
```

is there a way in Matlab to concatenate them and produce the **binary number** 101010101010010101000101010?

Comment: Do you want the concatenated binary string or the decimal equivalent of the concatenated binary string? (if it's the latter, you can use the `bin2dec` function in combination with any of the OPs' answers.)

Comment: yeah not clear what you want, perhaps a vector of logicals? ie: `[a,b,c] - '0'`

Comment: I need the concatenated string, say, d = strcat(a, b, c), to be a binary number, not the decimal equivalent of strcat output

Comment: You're mixing things up, the concatenated result is the binary **representation** *saved* in char format.

Comment: I need it in binary...

Comment: Repeating a word doesn't add informative content, nor gets us closer to what you want to get.

Comment: @Bob: are you familiar with MATLAB data types: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the concatenation operator `[ ]`, with horizontal concatenation `,` (vertical concatenation `;` will fail here unless you `reshape()` into column vectors):

```
[a,b,c]
```

However, I suggest storing your variables in a cell array:

```
s = {'101010101010','010101', '000101010'};
[s{:}]
```

or

```
cat(2,s{:})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work:

```
res = [a,b,c]
```

or alternatively call

`res = strcat(a,b,c)`

or, yet

`res = cat(2,a,b,c)`

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings, you could say:

```
out = [a b c];
```

Alternatively:

```
out = strcat(a,b,c);
```

Yet another way:

```
out = sprintf('%s', a,b,c);
```